# Replace #N/A error when using R1C1 as Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the below code to do a fast vlookup, however I'm struggling when the code returns "#N/A" errors.

I've tried to copy and paste special in the hope that the "N/A" will be treated like regular text (then I can replace with any value I want), but that doesn't seem to work.

My code as follows:

```
lr1 = Worksheets("Risk Explorer greeks").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

Range("J2:J" & lr1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R1C1:R50000C1, 1, False)"
```

Would appreciate any help! Any ideas on how I can get rid of these "#N/A" errors using VBA?

Comment: Try: `Range("J2:J" & lr1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R1C1:R50000C1, 1, False),""some other text"")"`

Comment: Can you also use this Vlookup to lookup data on other tabs in the worksheet, or do you need to have all of the data on the same sheet?

Comment: You can lookup data anywhere as long as you reference the correct ranges.

Comment: Is this the correct use to lookup data in another sheet?  Range("J2:J" & lr1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1], Sheets("Risk").R1C1:R50000C1, 1, False),""some other text"")"

Comment: No -it's the same syntax you would use in a cell: `Range("J2:J" & lr1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Risk!R1C1:R50000C1, 1, False),""some other text"")"`

Comment: Perfect - thanks for your help (again)!

Comment: Tip - if you want VBA to create a formula but it is failing, instead, make it just assign the text of that formula to a string and make a msgbox appear showing the value of the string (or debug running through line by line to see that value). Then copy that string verbatim into Excel. Does Excel give you an error when you try to enter the formula?